# Parse GeoJSON without create new layer on googlemap

Tags: java

I need to add points in googlemap from data in GeoJSON format.

I do it like this:

```
GeoJsonLayer layer = new GeoJsonLayer(googleMap, objPegsGeoJson);
for (GeoJsonFeature feature : layer.getFeatures()) {
    generalCoordinates = feature.getProperty("general_coordinates");


    String[] latlong =  generalCoordinates.split(",");
                    double latitude = Double.parseDouble(latlong[0]);
                    double longitude = Double.parseDouble(latlong[1]);
                    Marker mrk = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude))
                            .anchor(0.5f, 0.5f)
                    );
}
```

The problem is that I don't want to use another layer for googleMap as GeoJsonLayer, can I loop and parse this data without GeoJsonLayer?

Comment: You can loop through the `GeoJSON` and add markers straight to the Map without `GeoJsonLayer`. Just create a `JSONObject` variable and use your `GeoJSON` variable as parameter. Then create a `JSONArray` variable by using the `getJSONArray()`-method.

Now you can use a for-loop to iterate through the `JSONArray` by using `JSONObject` and the `Marker` class.